# How to can extract all icons from an .eps file?

Tags: icon, best-practice, eps

## I Have

**shutterstock_219776725.eps** that I downloaded from http://www.shutterstock.com/ , it looks like this when I open it in Photoshop.

[image]

---

## I want

to export all those icons in there into its own pieces so I can use them on  my website.

---

## I've tried

doing this manually one-by-one is very time-consuming, now I'm thinking to automate export all of them.

---

## Questions

Is there any Mac application out there that help me achieve this such task ?
What is the fastest way to extract all the icons from that .eps file ?

---

> Update

## Layer

After loading my **shutterstock_219776725.eps** in Illustartor. I see one layer.
When I click on the left arrow, I see all the sublayers.

[image]

---

## I've also tried

follow this link  : http://blog.iconfinder.com/how-to-export-multiple-layers-to-svg-files-in-adobe-illustrator/

And use this script (Export-Layers-as-PNG.jsx): http://blog.iconfinder.com/how-to-export-multiple-layers-to-svg-files-in-adobe-illustrator/

Place that script in here : /Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2014/Presets.localized/en_US/Scripts/Export-Layers-as-PNG.jsx

Then, I tried to export using the script.
I still couldn't see anything  exported.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. It is more of a general tactical question and not that elementary. He needs to be given more of a strategy than detailed technical support. Maybe I don't understand the guidelines of this site...Will seek enlightenment

Comment: Based on your update I would recommend using artboards for export. Assuming the icons are spread out on a grid I would make a grid of artboards (you can also create rectangles and then convert them to artboards) and export those.

Answer (score 3):

Automation would be a waste of time unless you need to do this on a lot of images. The easy thing to do in Photoshop, is to drag out guides into a grid enclosing your icons. Then use the slice tool. Select the slice tool and look in the Options bar. There should be an option for "Slices from Guides". Then Photoshop will let you save each slice and assign URL's and so forth in the Save For Web dialogue. These tools are specifically designed for web developement.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm learning how to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else said Illustrator but didn't really go into a lot of detail.

Open the eps in Illustrator. Use the select tool (key command v) to drag a box around the icon you'd like to convert. Go to object > artboards > fit to selected art. The rest of the image will remain but won't be included in the png.

From there go to file>save for web and devices

After you've saved your png you can ctrl+z or command+z to step back until your artboard is back to normal and repeat.

Comment: But do you know how to export all of them at once. I'm trying to avoid exporting them one-by-one here. Please let me know if you do.

Comment: I know a sort of work around, but it still doesn't do it in one simple step.

Create a new document with the number of artboards being the number of icons. Going off your image you'd need 6 columns, you'd have to check the spacing in between as well as the icon size you'd want.

If you copy and paste the image in then the icons should fill the artboards. You can then save them for web as you did before, but you'll still have to do one artboard at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your time trying to help me. I'll just keep looking/researching until I find the best one. I'll answer it here. :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool that can automagically do this in one action. Both drawing slices in PS and drawing artboards in illustrator are sane options. The EPS format itself gives no structural guarantees for ensuring that this in fact can be done.

A software could be made to do this. How well it would work depends on strategy used. For this case its pretty trivial to do. How well it would work as a general tool is another thing. Which leads us to the point that its not really worth automating this with only one file. Although certainly a slice into grid tool could be scripted easily.

In this particular case you could do the following:  Select groups from the layers palette. From layers palette menu (small icon in upper right corner) choose release to layers. Then use export layers extension to export each layer. Note your icons would still retain the text which could be easily deleted before doing this.

Slicing to grid would also be pretty easy to do with imagemagick.

Answer (score -3):

1. Open in Adobe Illustrator.
2. Create artboards underneath icons.
3. Export artboards as PNG.

Comment: After Open it in Adobe Illustrator, can you tell me more ?

Comment: I've tried open it up as you suggested, run this script : http://www.ericson.net/files/illustrator-scripts/Export-Layers-as-PNG.jsx and see nothing is exported.

Comment: I did a lot of researches, and here is one of my fav link : http://blog.iconfinder.com/how-to-export-multiple-layers-to-svg-files-in-adobe-illustrator/

Comment: I basically follow their whole instruction there.

Comment: Well that's for exporting layers. Do you have layers?

Comment: When I clicked on the right arrow icon, I see layers, If I don't click, I don't see it.

Comment: Is it because all my layers is not in the root ? Illustartor is not my expertise, please kindly advise.

Comment: I kindly advice basic software training. Your question is not ideally suited here as it can be solved by reading the help files.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find those help files that help me solve what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Top menu bar on your screen > "help"

Comment: The key issue is: how many times are you going to do this? Are you going to be regularly producing icons for websites, or is this just a one time effort. Spending hours bogged down with Illustrator scripting is a waste of time, if you only need to do this once. This is the draw back of automation in graphic design. How do you know your files are going to be structured correctly for the script everytime. For automation to work, the initial conditions have to be exactly the same everytime. I run into this all the time.

Comment: True, that's why I think art boards are the way to go. Quickly created and can be re-exported as often as you like.

Comment: Just saw your answer. Artboards are the better slices. they can overlap and be exported at different sizes. Which is much better for Icons.